# Update statement Syntax (PostgreSQL-Redshift)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, amazon-redshift

In the time dimension we have added additional two columns called Fiscal Year and Fiscal Year Month which are to be populated. In our case Fiscal year starts from 
Sep 01 and ends on Aug 31. (For example - Sep 01, 2017 to Aug 31,2018 is Fiscal Year 2018). I am trying to write an update statement in PostgreSQL. 
(Logic - case when X.monthname in ('September','October','November','December') then (X.Year+1) else X.Year end)- But looks like I am not able to get the right syntax. Can you help build it ?

We have Date, Year, MonthName columns in our Time table which can be used in update statement.

Thanks.

Comment: _Don't_ store the date in separate components (month, year, etc.).  Instead, just store your dates in a single date/datetime column.  Continuing with your current design will only cause problems later on.

Comment: Can you provide the exact syntax you are using and error you are getting? `UPDATE testtable
SET fiscalyear = CASE WHEN month IN ('September','October','November','December') THEN year+1 ELSE year END` should work, Tim's legitimate concerns notwithstanding. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36f176/1/0)

Comment: but do we need to put a join condition on Date field ? I tried executing the above one but received an error ( single query multiple rows )

Comment: Hey, Thanks It worked... I was able to update Fiscal Year. and now I want to  update fiscal year month. The above update statement worked.

Comment: Which one is it? Redshift or Postgres? Those two are quite different

Comment: :-) It's PostgreSQL - We have just found a way to update fiscal yearmonth also, based on the fiscal year value and yearnonthname..

Comment: If it's Postgres, then remove Redshift from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `update` would look like:

```
update x
    set Year = Year + 1
    where x.monthname in ('September', 'October', 'November', 'December') ;
```